# ogr2ogr - Lost projection when converting geojson to MapInfo Tab

Tags: geojson, mapinfo, ogr2ogr

I have the following geojson that I would like to convert to MapInfo tab with ogr2ogr: `ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo Tab" output.tab input.geojson`

geojson:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",  
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3857"
      }
   },
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[[-7551132, 6293816],[-7560916, 6260489]],
         },
         "properties":{
            "id":36
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

However, the output MapInfo Tab does not include the projection defined in the geojson.

Using ogrinfo on output.tab: `ogrinfo -ro -al output.tab`

```
Layer name: output
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-7560915.990000, 6260488.995000) - (-7551132.000000, 6293815.995000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
id: Integer (0.0)
OGRFeature(output2):1
  id (Integer) = 36
  Style = PEN(w:1px,c:#000000,id:"mapinfo-pen-2,ogr-pen-0")
  LINESTRING (-7551132.0 6293815.995,-7560915.99 6260488.995)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears its a known issue with the MapInfo Tab (mitab) format as we can see in this old osgeo ticket here: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/481

MapInfo Tab format may have problem to recognize projection by name.

**EDIT: Using linked crs instead of named crs in the geojson is not working neither.**

**EDIT 2: This issue was corrected in the trunk version of gdal since 2015-09-18. This patch will be present in the next official release after this date.**

Answer (score 2):

I would write mail about this to gdal-dev mailing list because this may be a bug in the MapInfo driver. Compare with the OGC WKT output from gdalsrsinfo:

```
gdalsrsinfo epsg:3857

PROJ.4 : '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=
0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs'

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +
x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

Comment: I have found that its an old bug in mitab format: trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/481